# Как получить cglib proxy из Spring?

Tags: java, spring, proxy, spring-aop

Я хочу перехватить метод следующего простого класса:

```
public class MessageWriter {
    public void writeMessage() {
        System.out.print("method");
    }
}
```

с помощью перехватчика методов CGLIB:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor;
import net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy;

public class CglibInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable {
        System.out.print("Cglib ");
        Object res = method.invoke(obj, args); 
        System.out.print(" proxy!");
        return res;
    }
}
```

И я могу получить cglib прокси с помощью cglib Enchancer:

```
CglibInterceptor cglibInterceptor = new CglibInterceptor(target);
MessageWriter cgLibProxy = (MessageWriter) Enhancer.create(MessageWriter.class, cglibInterceptor);
System.out.println("\ncglib proxy: ");
cgLibProxy.writeMessage();
```

Этот код работает. Однако я не могу понять, как получить cglib прокси из `org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory` или из `org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create()`, т.е. cglib-proxy из Spring?

Если я пишу следующий код:

```
MessageWriter cgLibSpringProxy = (MessageWriter) org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(MessageWriter.class, cglibInterceptor);
```

eclipse подчёркивает `create` красным:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD**

Если более точно переформулировать мой вопрос, меня интересует, **можно ли как-нибудь указать в коде, что нужно использовать именно CGlib прокси, в случае, если целевой класс реализует интерфейс?** Ведь "по умолчанию , когда целевой объект, оснащаемый советом, реализует какой-то интерфейс, для создания экземпляров прокси целевого объекта Spring будет использовать динамический прокси JDK". Вроде как в конфигурационном файле для этого можно указать

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
    <!-- other beans defined here... -->
</aop:config>
```

а вот в коде это как-нибудь можно сделать? И вроде как у класса `ProxyFactory` есть метод `setProxyTargetClass`:

```
ProxyFactory pf = new ProxyFactory () ;
pf.setProxyTargetClass(true);
```

но по описанию в документации я всё-таки не поняла, ТОЧНО ли установка этого метода в `true` обязывает Spring использовать именно CGLIB для создания прокси? Вроде как нет? Из документации о [ProxyConfig.setProxyTargetClass():](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/framework/ProxyConfig.html#setProxyTargetClass(boolean)))

> Set this to "true" to force proxying for the TargetSource's exposed
>   target class. If that target class is an interface, a JDK proxy will
>   be created for the given interface. If that target class is any other
>   class, a CGLIB proxy will be created for the given class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сколько я знаю, `CGlib` используется по умолчанию при создании прокси без интерфесов в `Spring`:

```
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor;
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;
import org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory;

public class SpringAop {

    public static class Entity {
        public void soSomething() {
            System.out.println("doing something");
        }
    }

    public static class Handler implements MethodInterceptor {

        @Override
        public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("before calling method");
            Object returnedValue = methodInvocation.proceed();
            System.out.println("after calling method");
            return returnedValue;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Entity entity = new Entity();

        ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory();
        proxyFactory.setTarget(entity);
        proxyFactory.addAdvice(new Handler());

        Entity entityProxy = (Entity) proxyFactory.getProxy();
        entityProxy.soSomething();
    }
}
```

**Дополнение:**

Дело в том, что если цель (`target`) не имеет интерфейсов, то прокси будет создан через наследование от цели. Для этого будет использован `cglib`. В противном случае, применяется `AspectJ`.

Comment: Вроде как наоборот, по умолчанию используется jdk dinamic proxy: "По умолчанию, когда целевой объект, оснащаемый советом,
реализует какой-то интерфейс, для создания экземпляров прокси целевого объекта
Spring будет использовать динамический прокси JDK. Однако если целевой объект,
оснащаемый советом, не реализует интерфейс (например, из-за того, что представляет
собой конкретный класс), то для создания экземпляров прокси будет применяться
CGLIВ".

Comment: Хотя в этом примере, который Вы привели, наверняка Spring будет использовать как раз CGlib, т.к. Entity не реализует никаких интерфейсов.

Comment: @Ksenia да, в примере выше нет интерфейсов, значит прокси будет создан с использованием наследования через `cglib`.

Comment: А явно как-нибудь можно указать в коде, что нужно использовать именно CGlib прокси? Вроде как в конфиге для этого можно указать <aop:config proxy-target-class=">, а вот в коде это как-нибудь можно сделать?

Comment: @Ksenia в смысле? Если вам нужен сам `cglib`, то можно воспользоваться самим `cglib` без `spring` как вы показали выше.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы Spring использовал cglib прокси в любом случае, даже если целевой класс реализует интерфейс.

Comment: Да: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089200/what-is-cglib-in-spring-framework

Comment: @Ksenia Стало интересно как сделать это напрямую. Покапался в исходниках и нашел такой класс (но он сделан на уровне доступа пакета): https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/1e07468d20c49baeb441425c7d0df053cb5d3cd1/spring-aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/framework/CglibAopProxy.java

Comment: @Ksenia кстати, каким способом был создан прокси-бин можно по его имени в дебаге. У спринга есть два типа имен для прокси - с помощью `JdkDynamicAopProxy` в слове и `EnhancerBySpring` какой-то сторонней библиотекой, типа `cglib`.

Answer (score 1):

Аннотация @Scope позволяет указать способ создания прокси. Можно форсировать использование CGLIB, даже если класс имеет интерфейс. Вот так:

```
@Service
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MyService impements SomeInterface { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня работает такой код:

```java
import org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer;
import org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor;

    // ...

        Model model = new Model(1, "test");
        MethodInterceptor callback = (object, method, args, methodProxy) -> methodProxy.invoke(model, args);
        Model proxy = (Model) Enhancer.create(Model.class, callback);
        assertThat(proxy).isEqualTo(model);
```